# Modify background color in Pandas plot?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I'm currently using Pandas direct plot (df.plot) in Python 2.7. It has worked great except it leaves me with a gray background. Is it possible to modify this color (eg. set it to white?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure

You can use the ax object the plot function returns.

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(0, 100), 'B': np.random.uniform(1, 100, 100)})
ax = my_df.plot(kind='scatter', x='A', y='B')
ax.set_facecolor('black')
```